# Show that $x \cos(cx)$ is aperiodic

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

I'm using the function $f(x)=x~cos(cx)$ in a paper and the periodicity of the function is relevant. Is there a simple way to show that a function of this form is aperiodic, or is it reasonable to simply state that it is aperiodic because of the multiplication with $x$?

By aperiodic I mean that in the following equation $T$ must be $0$:

$$x~\cos(cx) = (x+T) ~\cos(c(x+T)).$$

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and $c$ is a constant.

Comment: It is quite hard that an unbounded continuous function is periodic.

Comment: In fact if $f$ is a continuous periodic function with period $T>0$, consider $f$ on a compact (closed and bounded) interval of length $T$, for example $[0,T]$. By continuity, $f$ has a (finite) maximum on this compact set. By periodicity, that maximum is the global maximum for $f$. Therefore $f$ is bounded above. The same kind of argument shows $f$ is bounded below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $c=0$ it's obvious.
If $c>0$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{2\pi n}{c}\cos\left(c\frac{2\pi n}{c}\right)=+\infty $$
and 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\frac{\pi+2n\pi}{c}\cos\left(c\frac{\pi+2\pi n}{c}\right)=-\infty $$
therefore it's not periodic. For $c<0$ you the proof goes the same.

Comment: So, a function with an unbounded range is not periodic?

Comment: Yes, but only if it's continuous.

Comment: Great. Thanks :)